# WPF behaviour not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, attachedbehaviors

I was trying to create a wpf behaviour.What I do is look for the keystrokes `OemPeriod`,`Decimal` , `backspace` and `delete`. If the string in the textbox is `101.55`, and the user presses the Decimal or OemPeriod by moving the cursor back to 10, it will remove the string 1 after 10 and the string will become `10.55` .

That part is working as intended. but the real problem is with the `back (backspace)` and `Delete` keys.

If the text in the textbox is `10.55` and the cursor is after the `.` (caret index= 2) and the user presses backspace, the caret is  shifting its position by -1(before the decimal) and it is adding the `55` after the caret position and the text becomes `1055.00`and the same happens for the `Delete`key.

**the text is formatted using `StringFormat={}{0:#.00}`**

Here is my code, can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
public class DecimalWatchingBehaviour : Behavior<UIElement> 
{

     protected override void OnAttached() 
     {
        base.OnAttached();
        TextBox t = AssociatedObject as TextBox;
        if (t != null) 
        {
            t.PreviewKeyUp += shiftCaretPosition;
        }
     }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        TextBox t = AssociatedObject as TextBox;
        if (t != null) 
        {
            t.PreviewKeyUp -= shiftCaretPosition;
        }
    }

    private void shiftCaretPosition(object sender, KeyEventArgs args) 
    {
        TextBox t = sender as TextBox;
        if (t == null) return;
        string txt = t.Text;
        if (!txt.Contains(".")) 
        {
            return;
        }
        int index = txt.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal);
        int caretIndex = t.CaretIndex;
        if ((args.Key == Key.OemPeriod || args.Key == Key.Decimal)) 
        {
            t.Text = t.Text.Remove(t.CaretIndex, index);
            t.CaretIndex = t.Text.IndexOf(".", StringComparison.Ordinal) + 1;
        } else if (args.Key == Key.Back && txt.Substring(caretIndex < index ? caretIndex : index,
            caretIndex < index ? index - caretIndex : caretIndex - index) == ".") 
        {
            t.CaretIndex = index - 1;
        } else if (args.Key == Key.Delete && txt.Substring(caretIndex < index ? caretIndex : index,
            caretIndex < index ? index - caretIndex : caretIndex - index) == ".") 
        {
            t.CaretIndex = index + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the xaml namespace declaration

```
xmlns:behaviour="clr-namespace:Utils.UI.Input.Behaviour;assembly=Utils"
<UserControl.Resources>        
        <behaviour:DecimalWatchingBehaviour x:Key="decimalWatchingBehaviour" />
</UserControl.Resources>
```

And the textbox in xaml

```
<TextBox
        Margin="5"
        Text="{Binding NewBatch.Cess,
               Mode=TwoWay,
               UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
               StringFormat={}{0:#.00}}" >
        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <behaviour:DecimalWatchingBehaviour/>
        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: I added the `TextBox` with `PreviewKeyDown` and in the handler did the same as you described. After pressing backspace with input `10.55` caret being after the `.` the Text became `0.55` not `1055.00`. Can't reproduce.

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi, Sorry... , I missed an important part that the text in the textbox is formatted using `StringFormat={}{0:#.00}`. I've edited my question.Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: Added `Text="{Binding SomeDoubleProperty, StringFormat={}{0:#.00}}"`. Still can't reproduce. I get the same result with or without the `StringFormat`

Comment: that is not in the code behind it is an `attached behaviour` as i said in the question. if it was written in the code behind i'll have to repeat the code may times for every window

Comment: It doesn't matter where it is, I assume your behavior just attaches an event handler to `AssociatedObject`'s `PreviewKeyDown` event anyway and runs this code. But feel free to actually update your post with the behavior and all necessary code if you feel that might be important and might give us a real chance to help.

Comment: you are right i'm attaching the `previewkeydown` event. i'll update my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105046/discussion-between-sony-and-szabolcs-dezsi).

Comment: @SzabolcsDézsi I've updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can refer to the following simple event handler code snippet, which provides similar functionality, namely: restricting WPF `TextBox1` input to numeric entry and some special keys:

```
// PreviewKeyDown event proc: 
// only numeric and some special keys input allowed
TextBox1.PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
{
    // intercept modifier "SHIFT" key
    if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
    { e.Handled = true; }

    // cast e.Key to int
    int _intKey = (int)e.Key;

    // allow the following key
    if (e.Key == Key.Back ||
        e.Key == Key.Delete ||
        e.Key == Key.Enter ||
        e.Key == Key.Return ||
        e.Key == Key.Tab ||
        e.Key == Key.OemPeriod ||
        e.Key == Key.OemComma ||
        e.Key == Key.Decimal ||
        e.Key == Key.Left ||
        e.Key == Key.Right ||
        (_intKey <= 43 && _intKey >= 34) ||
        (_intKey <= 84 && _intKey >= 73)) 
        {
              // the rest of the event handling code
              return;
        }
    else e.Handled = true;
};
```

where `TextBox1` is the target WPF TextBox control of interest. There is no need for any additional XAML or code behind.

Hope this may help.